# Problemas con los acentos en consulta Eloquent utilizando pluck()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo problemas con una consulta eloquent al momento de usar la herramienta de collection **pluck**

En la BDD se guarda perfectamente el acento

[image: En la BDD esta perfectamente guardado con su acento]

Consulta utilizando Eloquent

```
$listFinal[].=FAQ::where("id",$ids)->get()->pluck('answer');
```

Resultado final impreso con blade

```
cami\u00f3n
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez esté mal la codificación de caratceres en tu vista, para ello agrega esta etiqueta dentro tu `<head>`

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

o

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
// Esto solo en el caso de que tu navegador no soporte HTML5
```

Si no funciona es posible que necesites cambiar el charset de tu base de datos. Parece que estás usando phpmyadmin, así que hazlo así

- Ve a *phpmyadmin*
- En el panel de la izquiera selecciona la base de datos.
- Ve hacia ***Operations*** en la barra de menú.
- En ***Collation*** selecciona `ut8_general_ci`
- Finalmente presiona ***Go*** para guardar la configuración

Despúes de eso los caracteres ya deberían venir correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

en la config/database.php tienes que mirar esto

```
'mysql' => array(
'driver'    => 'mysql',
'host'      => 'localhost',
'database'  => '',
'username'  => '',
'password'  => '',
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => 'false',
),
```

prueba a cambiar la codificación a la que tienes en tu database